# How to enable custom actuator endpoint for a child project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to enable custom endpoint for a project that's inside other project.

I have a parent project with its pom.xml, then inside that project I have zuul-gateway project which has its own pom.xml with the parent set to parent project.

I do everything correctly in terms of enabling custom endpoint because I've tried the solution on a standalone project (no child-parent relationship) and it works, but when I try to use it in a child project the endpoint gets ignored.

```
web:
  exposure:
    include: info, health, metrics, microservices-health
```

The three metrics before (info, health, metrics) my custom one (microservices-health) get mapped correctly to actuator, while my custom one gets completely ignored.

EDIT: the spring boot version used is 2.0.x

Comment: what do you mean by child project? You have to configure on the app level. If you include another JAR this configuration is not loaded

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/GrEdGhB)

Here is the picture of the project structure. Im trying to configure custom endpoint in the actuator directory of a 'zuul-gateway' project.

Comment: That will not work.You have to configure that on the project that contains @SpringBootApplication and the main class

Comment: I've fixed it. The problem was that the starting class was inside the /boot directory and the component scan didn't scan anything inside /actuator directory then. When I moved ZuulApp a level above, it mapped correctly. Hope I make any sense...

Comment: Yes perfect. I suggest that you add this as the answer of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it. The problem was that the starting class was inside the /boot directory and the component scan didn't scan anything inside /actuator directory then. When I moved ZuulApp (starting class) a level above, it mapped correctly.